# 3 tables in SQL

Tags: python, sql, mysql

Lets say i have 3 tables: `users`, `posts` and `comments`.

`users` - contains information about registered users

`posts` - contains information about posts that were created by users

`comments` - all comments on one or multiple posts created by one or multiple users

[image]
.

This image is how my `comments` table looks like. `user_id` and `post_id` are foreign keys in this table but primary keys in `users` and `posts` tables respectively. However this structure doesn't seem right to me because as you can see the `post_id` and `user_id` may get repeated multiple times.

My question is - is this structure good and should i use this, or should i create a new "middleman" table to hold `user_id` and `post_id` in order to somehow reduce redundancy? If so, how? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Shouldn't this be placed in stackoverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your example means that, say, comment #1 is by user 8 about post 2,
and comment #2 is by user 9 about post 7 then you're doing it right.  This is a classic method to organize a table that relates the contents of other tables; you can use it to get all the comments on a particular post, or all the comments by a particular user, and so on.  Since the answers to those questions are "some, one, or more" the repeated values are not a problem.  If you saw the same exact combination in all three columns that might indicate a poor design -- but in this case it looks pretty appropriate.

The table as shown does not have a column for the actual comment data; you could add that here or foreign key to another table that contained the actual comment text.